# Porque split de un string no me devuelve la cadena? devuelve System.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo unas variables de `session[]` creadas en mi aplicación las cuales debo ocupar en la vista para mostrar esa información que tiene almacenada en memoria. La pregunta es ¿Como puedo leer esa ´session[]´ en la vista pero solo una parte del texto que contienen?. Ejemplo:

Las siguientes ´session[]´ creadas:

```
Session["varUno"] = "Texto uno";
Session["varDos"] = "Texto dos";
Session["varTres"] = "Texto tres";
```

Estaba tratando de leerlas de esta forma:

```
@Session["varUno"].ToString().Split(' ');
```

Para que quedara de esta forma: Texto  (sin el texto uno) pero me devuelve algo de System.Net....

Los datos vienen asi, para que no me digan y si mejor le dejas solo la palabra Texto para crear la Session...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

La solucion fue agregar un ´.First()´ al final de la llamada para recuperar la `session`.

```
@Session["varUno"].ToString().Split(' ').First();
```

*"resulta que split devuelve un array de strings. Entonces te devolvia lo que pusiste arriba, porque tenia un array y al tratar de transformarlo en string veias solo el nombre de la clase (que es lo que devolvia por defecto la propiedad tostring()). Entonces, al hacer first, estas aplicando linq para devolver el primer valor de ese array, que es el que vos queres"*

Espero que le pueda servir a alguien mas. =)

Comment: si, pero no sabes porque no? resulta que split devuelve un array de strings. Entonces te devolvia lo que pusiste arriba, porque tenia un array y al tratar de transformarlo en string veias solo el nombre de la clase (que es lo que devolvia por defecto la propiedad tostring()). Entonces, al hacer first, estas aplicando linq para devolver el primer valor de ese array, que es el que vos queres. O explicas esto en la respuesta, o realmente es bastante pobre.

Comment: Si me percate al momento de depurar el código, de todas formas agregue parte de tu comentario a la respuesta.

Comment: También podrías hacer `@Session["varUno"].ToString().Split(' ')[0];`